# Delete leaf with same value in a binary tree

Tags: binary-tree

i need a pseudocode that, with a give binary tree T, with a value in each node , search and delete all leaf with a sibling with the same value.
I need an optimal complexity pseudocode.

i guess it shouls be samething like this

```
deleteCopy(TREE T)  
if T != nil then
  if T.left = null and T.right = null
    if T.parent.right.left = null and T.parent.right.right = null
      if T.parent.left.value = T.parent.right.value then
        delete T
  deleteCopy(T.left())
  deleteCopy(T.right())
```

Is it correct?

Comment: Is there a value in *each node*, or only in leaf nodes? If the former, how would you deal with two internal nodes that have the same value, or where the sibling of a leaf node is an internal node, but has the same value?

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert on this, but you should use a traversal algorithm.

```
inOrderSearch(Node n)
   inOrderSearch(n.left)
   check(n)
   inOrderSearch(n.right)

check(Node n)
   right = n.right
   left = n.left
   if right.left == null && right.right == null && left.left == null && left.right == null
       if right.value == left.value
           n.left = null
```

I chose in-order traversal, but level-order is better in that case.
in check subroutine,

1. get two siblings(children of a node)
2. in the first if statement, it checks if they are both a leaf.
3. in the second if statement it checks
4. if they are equal. if they are equal, it deletes the left node. It is up to you.

you may start searching with root node.

Comment: Understood, simply i should check the value of the leaf starting from theire parent. thanks for the answer.